# How to reset a form after custom validation using bootstrap 4.0

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to reset my contact form after successful submission using AJAX/PHP, I am using the bootstrap 4.0 custom styles form validation javascript, where it adds an "form.addEventListener('submit', function(event))" to the form.

After successful submission, when I try to reset the form using the "reset()" function or by assigning null to individual input text fields, the validation script is getting activated and my custom error messages are displayed, I guess this is because of the "form.addEventListener" event is active! please provide a viable solution to reset the form, Thank You.

Comment: If you are sending the data by AJAX - why are you submitting the form? - simply reset the form values after the AJAX data is returned and prevent form submission entirely.

Answer (score 1):

As the EventListener is active the reset option does not work, we need to first removeClass "was-Validated" and than reset the form, this worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct flow. ```form.classList.remove("was-validated"); form.reset();```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function send(self){
 self.reset();
 return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="return send(this);">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```